# Can I backup a 1TB drive onto a 750GB drive?

Tags: hard-disk, dd

I want to backup a larger harddrive (1000GB), but sadly, I only have a smaller harddrive (750GB) available. In this particular case, I do **not** want to copy over the files, I want to backup the harddrive **bit by bit**:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

What's obviously going to happen is after copying 750GB worth of data, `dd` is going to give up and tell me there isn't enough storage space left on the thaget drive. This is fine; my hopes are that the only information I will ever need to recover will be in the first 500GB, but I'd prefer to copy as much as I can, as this 500GB amount is just an estimate.

My question is, will I still be able to mount `/dev/sdb` later and open or recover whatever data it was able to save, even if only `75%` of the data is there, and `dd` was stopped in the middle of the copying?

Comment: In my particular case, `/dev/sda` _might_ be dying, and in an effort to be _"better safe than sorry"_, I want to copy over as much data and possible to another smaller drive (`/dev/sdb`) _in case_ it ends up failing. However, I asked the question in a generic way so the answers can benefit more people than just me.

Comment: The real question is: do you have 1TB or 750GB of data in the drive?

Comment: As a temporary measure, you might be able to save all the data, but _not_ in an immediately mount-able form, by using: `gzip -c /dev/sda >/dev/sdb`

Answer (score 1):

The smaller disk may be enough storage if either there is enough free space on the bigger disk or the used space can be compressed below the size of the smaller disk.

Usually I would suggest to overwrite all the empty space with zeroes before making a compressed sector copy but this is not a good idea when a drive is failing.

I suggest to make a file system on the smaller disk (if not already), mount it and write (for each partition to be saved) a compressed (e.g.) tar file to it:

```
tar -cjf /mnt/smalldisk/bigdisk.tbz /bigdisk/partition
```

If the tar file requires more space than available you should be able to restore nearly all that could be written (except for the last unfinished file).

Answer (score 1):

I would just use something simple like delete the crap you don't need, then use gparted to shrink the hard drive partition and then copy it over.

Answer (score 0):

No, don't do that.  As you figured, you are likely to lose up to 25% of the data on the drive doing that, and also have a hard time recovering what is left.  As long as you are able to mount the disk and copy the files, you should do that rather than try to use `dd`.

Even if you can't mount the drive, your next tactic is to use `dump` ( assuming you are using ext[234] ) to try and back it up.  It is quite likely to be able to recover much of whatever can be recovered from the drive ( unless it has been marked as intentionally deleted ), and store it on the smaller drive in a form that can easily be extracted piecemeal or restored outright, and the backup can be compressed so even if the source drive is nearly full it may still fit compressed on the smaller drive.